# How to show time for different time zones in AnalogClock() widget using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

How to change the time in the clock for different time zones?

```
     AnalogClock(
      textScaleFactor: 1.8,
      showAllNumbers: true,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(width: 2.0, color: Colors.black),
          color: Colors.transparent,
          shape: BoxShape.circle),
    );
```

Comment: Perhaps by asking this package https://pub.dev/packages/time_machine for the time in a particular place.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the time through the `dateTime` property in that.Use `toLocal()` method to get the equivalent date/time value specified in the current time zone. You can get the current time zone from `dataTime.timeZoneName` property from dateTime object. Hope it will help you.

```
final dataTime = DataTime.now().toLocal();

AnalogClock(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(width: 2.0, color: Colors.black),
        color: Colors.transparent,
        shape: BoxShape.circle),
    width: 150.0,
    isLive: true,
    hourHandColor: Colors.black,
    minuteHandColor: Colors.black,
    showSecondHand: false,
    numberColor: Colors.black87,
    showNumbers: true,
    textScaleFactor: 1.4,
    showTicks: false,
    showDigitalClock: false,
    datetime: dataTime,
    );
```

Comment: Read the question again. question is how to show time with different time zones